# Div is moving up (and over) a resizable div on resize

Tags: jquery, css, drag-and-drop, draggable, jquery-ui-resizable

Sorry for the title, I didn't know how to explain the issue properly.

I am trying to add divs to a container and be able to move them around to position them. If you look at [this fidddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NFBtp/2/) and hover over the div (not the red one, the one wrapping it), you will be able to click the "New Container" button and it will add a container. However, if you resize this container, you will see the div below it jump up on top of it.

Am I doing something wrong or is this intended functionality? I don't want any overlap and would ideally like the new div to either be above or below the existing div (based on where you drag it).

**EDIT:**

To recreate the issue, please hover next to the red box (not on) and you will see a selection box appear. Click once when this appears and then click the New Container button. This will add a div above the red box. If you try and re-size the red box then the red div moves up.

**EDIT 2**

Ok I have noticed "why" this is happening. JQuery changes the element to be absolutely positioned on resize so this stops the float working. Is there any way to remove this?

Html:

```
<div class="editable_content" style="padding:10px;">
    <div style="width: 100%; padding:10px; height: 400px;">
        <div style="width:100%; float:left; height:100px; background:red"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<input type="button" id="new_container" value="New Container" />
```

CSS:

```
.edit_mouse_on {
    background-color: #bcd5eb !important;
    outline: 2px solid #5166bb !important;
}
.edit_selected {
    outline: 2px solid red !important;
}

.ui-resizable-helper { border: 2px dotted #00F; }
```

JS:

```
var prevElement = null;
var selectedElement;
var enableHoverAction = true;
var allowedEditableClasses = "editable_content"
var hoverClass = "edit_mouse_on";
var selectedClass = "edit_selected";

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
    var elem = e.target || e.srcElement;
    if (prevElement != null) detach(prevElement);
    attach(elem);
    prevElement = elem;
}, true);

function attach(obj) {
    if (enableHoverAction) {
        if (obj != null) {
            if ($(obj).parents("div.editable_content").length) {
                $(obj).addClass(hoverClass);
                $(obj).bind("click", function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    select(this);
                });
            }
        }
    }
}

function select(obj) {
    selectedElement = obj;
    enableHoverAction = false;
    $(obj).addClass(selectedClass);
    $(obj).removeClass(hoverClass);
}

function detach(obj) {
    if (enableHoverAction) {
        if (obj != null) {
            $(obj).removeClass(hoverClass);
            $(obj).unbind("click");
        }
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#new_container").click(function () {
        $("<div/>", {
            "style": "border:1px solid black; width:100px;height:100px; float:left;margin-bottom:1px;display:inline;clear:both",
            text: "",
        }).resizable({
            helper: "ui-resizable-helper"
        }).draggable({
            cursor: "crosshair",
            cursorAt: {
                top: 0,
                left: 0
            }
        }).prependTo(selectedElement);
    });
});
```

Comment: The reason you have to add code is because a question with only a link to jsfiddle is not a good question. See this answer and others on meta for a better explanation. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/114944

Comment: And while we are on that, do you think you can update your question with the relevant code? :) Thanks.

Comment: The relevant code and example is in jsFiddle. There is no point posting it all here when I have linked to it however I will bulk out my post if need be ... Just read the Meta post. Makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: Well if you read the answer I linked to you'll find that if jsfiddle is inaccessible then no one will be able to help answer your question based on the information you supplied. So adding some code to your question will help people answer your question regardless of if they can use jsfiddle and will help give future user some context on the issue.

Comment: @MatthewGreen - Yeah, saw that after posting (Edited my comment to late I guess). Thanks for the clarification, it makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems my question is a duplicate in a fashion but I will post this as an answer as I think it may be more helpful then deleting my post (as I couldn't see anything when searching):

[How to prevent Resizable and Draggable elements from collapsing on each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6037464/how-to-prevent-resizable-and-draggable-elements-from-collapsing-on-each-other/6204793#6204793)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand what you're saying. But, this is the CSS for `#editor`:

```
width: 80%; // cool.
height: 150px; // alright.
float: left; // okidoke.
background-color: lightgrey; // pretty.
position: absolute; // wait. what?
bottom: 0; // k.
left: 0; // right.
position: fixed; // ok, what the heck.
margin-left: 10%; // sure, why not.
```

Again, I'm quite lost in what you're going for with the hovering, and the clicking "New Container" and the `$().resizable();` thing you mentioned. So, I'm just guessing here, but I think you want less crazy CSS.

The styles that end up being applied to that element is:

```
width: 80%;
height: 150px;
background-color: lightgray;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
position: fixed;
margin-left: 10%;
```

`position: absolute;` and `float: left` are invalidated by `position: fixed;`, and even that could be simplified to:

```
width: 80%;
height: 150px;
background-color: lightgray;
bottom: 0;
left: 10%;
position: fixed;
```

Anyway, `#editor` will sit on top of the content before it, as the position is `fixed`.

Hopefully this information helps out a little. If you have the time to elaborate on the problem in a kid-friendly way, I might be able to help out a little more!

Comment: My problem isn't to do with `#editor`. That's just a panel holding a button in my example. I will update my OP with more detailed information and simplify my example.

Comment: I have updated my OP and jsFiddle with more information and a simpler example without the edit container.