# Drag & Resize image underneath with a DIV above

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

Here is the scenario.

I have a logo which can be draggable & resizable via jQuery UI (version is 1.9.2, but it doesn't really matter), bounded by a parent DIV. It works well in dragging & resizing.

However, when I try to overlay a DIV with a background image exactly above, the mouse clicks are blocked by the DIV above.

**HTML**

```
<div id="appleLogo"></div>
<div id="frameBorder">
    <div id="draggableHelper" style="display:inline-block">
        <img id="image" src="http://www.google.com.br/images/srpr/logo3w.png" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#draggableHelper').draggable({
    containment: "#frameBorder",
    scroll: false
});
$('#image').resizable();
```

**CSS**

```
#appleLogo {
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background-image: url(http://wbridgewaterschools.org/school/images/Apple%20logo.png);
    background-size: cover;
    opacity: 0.7;
    filter: alpha(opacity=70);
    z-index: 10;
}
#frameBorder {
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid #F00;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

For better demonstration, here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shivanraptor/EVSZQ/). How can I bypass the above DIV ?

Here are some references I've read, but none applies to this case:

- [How to prevent Resizable and Draggable elements from collapsing on each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6037464/how-to-prevent-resizable-and-draggable-elements-from-collapsing-on-each-other/6204793#6204793)
- [Drag & Resize div overlapped other div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14156947/drag-resize-div-overlapped-other-div)

Comment: The answer is simple its not an outline based image so its blocking the background image..Its an image with a white background..Have you tried with outlined images ?

Comment: you mean transparent background? the problem still exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little css/html/js shuffle is all you needed, code is posted below and here is the fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/EVSZQ/10/

### HTML

```
<div id="frameBorder">
    <div id="draggableHelper" style="display:inline-block">
        <div id="image">
            <img id="logo" src="http://wbridgewaterschools.org/school/images/Apple%20logo.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#frameBorder {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid #F00;
}
#image {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-image: url(http://www.google.com.br/images/srpr/logo3w.png);
}
#logo {
    position: fixed;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    opacity: .55;
}
```

### JS

```
$('#draggableHelper').draggable({
    containment: "#frameBorder",
    scroll: false
});
$('#image').resizable();
```

Hope that helps!

Best,
Josh

Comment: the Apple logo does not have to resizable / draggable; only the Google logo requires.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor That is an easy fix, just change to `position: fixed;` for the logo class in the css. Here is the fiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/EVSZQ/10/](http://jsfiddle.net/EVSZQ/10/). I also updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

edit : new fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/EVSZQ/5/

Here is the js code : but i didn't optimize it in thinking that it will be easy to understand...

```
$('#image').resizable();
$('#draggableHelper').draggable({
    containment: "#frameBorder",
    scroll: false
});

$('#appleLogo').on('mousedown', function(event){
    var gxstart = $('#image').offset().left;
    var gxend = $('#image').offset().left + $('#image').width();
    var gystart = $('#image').offset().top;
    var gyend = $('#image').offset().top + $('#image').height();  

    var mouseX = event.clientX;
    var mouseY =event.clientY;

    if( gxstart < mouseX )
    {
        if ( mouseX < gxend )
        {
            if(gystart < mouseY)
            {
                if(mouseY < gyend)
                {   
                    $('#draggableHelper').trigger(event);
                }
            }
        }
    }    
});
```

Comment: but I want the draggable logo ( Google ) under the non-movable logo ( Apple ). How can I achieve ?

Comment: only for drag, don't find for resize... i don't know on which element trigger the click to make the resize....

Comment: the draggable part is still a problem.